# Why did opencv not fully clean what is drawn in previous frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, draw, opencv3.0, opencv

[image]
[image]
[image]
As you can see from above opencv leave the trace of drawn rectangle all over my image. what confuse me more is that because I take the image from video frame by frame the rectangle should not even have exist in next frame but when I use cv2.imwrite you can see that it left the trace of rectangle drawn on previous frame. Why is this happening?
Below is my sample code :

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.videosource)
while self.running:
    has_frame, frame = cap.read()
    if has_frame:
    #object detection stuff
    
       if object_detected:
           cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (0,255,0), thickness)
           if something_happened:
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (0, 255, 255), thickness)

   cv2.imwrite('frame',frame)
   cv2.namedWindow("output", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
   frame = cv2.resize(frame, (960, 540))
   cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
   key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
   if key == ord("q"):
        exit()
```

I put only part of code that related to drawing to make it easy to read, but if you need the full code i can post it here, but it is so long though

Comment: Are you using harr cascades by chance for detection

Comment: @TERMINATOR no. I am using openvino model to detect human. Here is the model documentation if you need it by any chance -->https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2018_R5/_docs_Retail_object_detection_pedestrian_rmnet_ssd_0013_caffe_desc_person_detection_retail_0013.html